# How to annotate results of iteration?

Tags: python, oop, methods, iteration, type-hinting

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type


T = TypeVar('T')


class ListElem(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T, nxt: ListElem[T] = None):
        self.value = value
        self.nxt = nxt


class LinkedList(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, elem_factory: Type[ListElem], head: ListElem[T] = None):
        self._elem_factory = elem_factory
        self._head = head

    def add(self, value: T):
        elem = self._elem_factory(value, self._head)
        self._head = elem

    def __iter__(self):
        self._next = self._head
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> ListElem[T]:
        if not self._next:
            raise StopIteration

        result = self._next
        self._next = self._next.nxt

        return result


def main():
    lst: LinkedList[int] = LinkedList(ListElem)
    lst.add(5)

    for elem in lst:
        print(elem.value)  # PyCharm see elem like int, not like ListElem


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This annotating `__next__` doesnt helps me

How can I annotate that `LinkedList` return `ListElem[T]` while iteration, not just `T`?

If I do it like this

```
lst: LinkedList[ListElem[int]]
```

I cannot annotate this int to method

```
def add(self, value: ?): # T = ListElem[int], but I wanna annotate value just like int
    pass
```

I dont wanna annotate LinkedList like

```
lst: LinkedList[ListElem[int], int]
```

Because `int` just repeating and annotate same - type of value inside `ListElem.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is a bug in PyCharm's static type checker.

That `elem` type should be inferred as `ListElem[int]` and is correctly inferred as such by `mypy` for example.

Your code still had a few issues. Mostly type-safety related (since you are already dealing with annotations), but a few other optimizations. One of which incidentally also fixes that PyCharm problem.

The most important one IMO is that you did not use the type parameter of `ListElem` in the `elem_factory` annotation. If you do, you'll be able to immediately bind the type argument upon initialization by passing a specified `ListElem[int]` class. Then you **don't need** to explicitly annotate `lst` in your `main` function. This also happens to satisfy/silence PyCharm.

Here is a version with my proposed changes that passes `mypy --strict` and should work as intended:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


class ListElem(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T, nxt: Optional[ListElem[T]] = None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.nxt = nxt


class LinkedList(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, elem_factory: type[ListElem[T]], head: Optional[ListElem[T]] = None) -> None:
        self._elem_factory = elem_factory
        self._head = head

    def add(self, value: T) -> None:
        self._head = self._elem_factory(value, self._head)

    def __iter__(self) -> LinkedList[T]:
        self._next = self._head
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> ListElem[T]:
        if self._next is None:
            raise StopIteration
        result = self._next
        self._next = self._next.nxt
        return result


def main() -> None:
    lst = LinkedList(ListElem[int])
    lst.add(5)
    for elem in lst:
        print(elem.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However it seems that PyCharm still does not identify `elem` as the correct type. But at least it is not complaining.